# React Admin. React does not recognize the "emptyWhileLoading" prop on a DOM element

Tags: list, react-admin

React Admin.
In my case, default layout components ( and ) return null when the data is loading. I use a custom layout component instead and I have to handle the case where the data is not yet defined.

And that means that the following failed on load with a “ReferenceError: data is not defined” error.

For fix this problem I want to use The  prop provides. When enabled,  won’t render its child until data is defined.

But I get Warning: React does not recognize the `emptyWhileLoading` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `emptywhileloading` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

How I can solve this problem?

```
export default props => (
  <List
    emptyWhileLoading
    pagination={ <Pagination /> }
    bulkActionButtons={ false }
    sort={{ field: 'id', order: 'DESC' }}
    filters={ <ListFilter /> }
    actions={ <ListActions /> }
    { ...props }
  >
    <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="name" />
      <TextField source="type" />
      <TextField source="created_by_username" />
      <FunctionField label="Created at" source="created_at" render={ (record, key) => record[key] ? formatDatetime(record[key]) : null } />
      <FunctionField label="Updated at" source="updated_at" render={ (record, key) => record[key] ? formatDatetime(record[key]) : null } />
      <AudienceActions />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

I used documentation React Admin https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#emptywhileloading

I added emptyWhileLoading in  component, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You can write a React component wrapper for your DOM element and remove any properties you don't need:

```
const WrapperDiv = (props) => {
  const {
    emptyWhileLoading, 
    ...rest
  } = props
  ...
  return <div {...rest}>Wrapper</div>
}
```